# Macro-like function in c

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have some c code with macro functions that I fail to understand its output,

```
#define COMP(A,B) ( ((A) * (A)) + ((B) * (B)) )
int main()
{
int x = 2, y= 3, z;
z= COMP(x++,++y);
printf("x = %d\n", x);
printf("y = %d\n", y);
printf("z = %d\n", z);
}
```

The output, on different compilers is 4 5 31, can someone illustrate why?

Comment: @JL2210 Probably not worth reopening, since I've already answered, but for the record, I don't believe the "obvious" question, [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/), is an appropriate duplicate, because there's a significant extra piece of the puzzle for this particular question, namely that the undefined behavior is introduced by the macro expansion.  (I suspect there's also a duplicate which covers that aspect, but I don't know what it is.)

Comment: I've now found and added the better duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is *undefined*.

The macro invocation `COMP(x++, ++y)` expands to

```
( ((x++) * (x++)) + ((++y) * (++y)) )
```

When we have an expression or subexpression like

```
x++ * x++
```

where the same variable, `x`, is modified twice, there is no rule to say which modification happens first.  (And before you ask: no, the parentheses don't change anything, and neither does precedence.)  For this reason, compilers don't have to do it one way or another, and this is what makes the code undefined: compilers don't have to do anything reasonable at all, because you're not supposed to write code that's undefined in the first place.

For the full story, see the canonical question [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

This is one of the reasons why "function-like" macros such as `COMP()` must be used carefully, or not at all.  There are basically three rules:

1. Parenthesize all the arguments in the macro definition
2. Parenthesize the whole definition
3. In general, don't invoke the macro on arguments with side effects

The `COMP` macro's definition follows rules 1 and 2, but the invocation `COMP(x++, ++y)` obviously violates rule 3.

See also question [question 10.1](http://c-faq.com/cpp/safemacros.html) in the old [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

For most if not all uses of function-like macros, inline functions are preferable.  If you had written

```
inline int comp(int x, int y) { return x*x + y*y; }
```

I think you would have gotten a more sensible result.  Inline functions are required to evaluate their arguments just as regular function calls do, so in this case when you call `comp(x++, ++y)` you get just one `x++` and one `++y`, meaning there's no undefined behavior, and a well-defined result.

---

As an additional point of possible interest, I've seen a version of this problem come up in production code, in a surprisingly natural, uncontrived situation.  Imagine you're writing a little stack-based arithmetic evaluator.  Ignoring stack overflow detection for the moment, you might start with something like

```
int stack[50];
int *stackp = stack;

#define Push(val) (*stackp++ = (val))
#define Pop() (*--stackp)
```

Then you can push some numbers on the stack with code like

```
Push(10);
Push(20);
```

Then you can implement arithmetic operators which pop numbers off the stack, perform an operation, and push the result.  Here's addition:

```
int x = Pop();
int y = Pop();
Push(x + y);
```

But almost immediately you realize, Who needs those temporary variables?, and you "simplify" it to

```
Push(Pop() + Pop());
```

But this Does Not Work, it gives you strange results, and the reason is that it expands to

```
(*stackp++ = ((*--stackp) + (*--stackp)));
```

which is mondo undefined.  (I remember helping a co-worker track this exact problem down in his code in 2003 or so.)